# Store two commands output to a variable in powershell

Tags: powershell

I have below command running in PowerShell.

```
Get-ChildItem $sourcefs -Recurse -Exclude $exclude | Copy-Item -Destination {Join-Path "$destfs\$Bdate" $_.FullName.Substring($source.length)}
```

I want to store the output of above command to variable but its not storing.
Following is the try but it failed.

```
$Cp = Get-ChildItem $sourcefs -Recurse -Exclude $exclude | Copy-Item -Destination {Join-Path "$destfs\$Bdate" $_.FullName.Substring($source.length)} 2>&1
```

Please suggest.

Comment: What information do you want in the variables?

Comment: want all the information of the command output.

Comment: It can be normal output or any error

Comment: Do you want the `Copy-Item` command as the output?  Or are you trying to put the whole of `Get-ChildItem ...` onwards into this variable?  Or something else?

Answer (score -1):

To set a variable to a block of code, declare the variable as a `[scriptblock]` and place curly brackets around the code to be assigned:

```
[scriptblock]$myCode = {get-childitem -path 'c:\temp\' -Recurse | ?{$_ -like '*.xml'}}
```

To view the code as a string, just output the variable:

```
$myCode
```

To execute the code & view the output, invoke the code:

```
$myCode.Invoke()
```